# Ruby: How to store and display a day of the week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm relatively new to Ruby. I need to keep track of a day of the week on my activity model. The code that I have so far doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. I am wondering if there is a better way.

So far, this is what I have in my form:

```
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :day %><br />
    <%= f.select :day, [['Sunday', 0], ['Monday', 1], ['Tuesday', 2], ['Wednesday', 3], ['Thursday', 4], ['Friday', 5], ['Saturday', 6]] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And when I need to display the day of the week:

```
<% days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] %>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= days[activity.day.to_i] %>
<% end %>
```

How can I do this better? Feel free to mention any library/gem that I may not be aware of.

### Solution:

Ruby provides the [`Date::DAYNAMES`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html) constant which is an array of days of the week. We can reuse that in our code:

```
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :day %><br />
    <%= f.select :day, Date::DAYNAMES.zip((0..6).to_a) %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= Date::DAYNAMES[activity.day.to_i] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: from programming point of view (regardless of RoR special classes/functions) I would expect all logic related to a day translation from one format to another to reside inside a stand alone class and not in the view directly.  This has nothing to do specificaly to Ruby, but all languages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ruby's [`Date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html) class already has a constant defined that holds the name of the days in an array: `Date::DAYNAMES`.

For example, you could do something like:

```
days = []
Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index { |x, i| days << [x, i] }
```

I don't know if I'd necessarily say that this is *better*, but you can definitely leverage what is already available to you.

Comment: "but you can definitely leverage what is already available to you". You SHOULD leverage what is already available. Reinventing the wheel is also reinventing the bugs.

Comment: @Adrian true that this question is tagged Ruby on Rails, so that will work, but it's also good to note that `Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK` will ONLY work in Rails. Also, depending on how you do your weeks, you'll get a different beginning of the week from what OP was looking for (Monday vs. Sunday).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way (RoR) is using the built-in constant:

```
Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK
# => 
{:monday=>0,
 :tuesday=>1,
 :wednesday=>2,
 :thursday=>3,
 :friday=>4,
 :saturday=>5,
 :sunday=>6}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions you can define an enum with that constant and then use it for different things:

In migration, day_of_week is integer

In model:

`enum :day_of_week => Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK`

And then you can use searches in model

`Model.day_of_weeks.keys[0..4]` will return ['monday', 'tuesday', .... 'friday']

`Model.monday` is equivalent to `Model.where("day_of_week = ?", 'monday')`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simplest, I would :

- save the plain text name of the day instead of number in `@activity.day`
- add a constant DAYS, it can live on your Activity model but may move to somewhere else in the future

Then it will looks like :

Model

```
DAYS = ['monday','tuesday',...]

validates_inclusion_of :day, :in => DAYS
```

View : form

```
<%= f.collection_select :day, Activity::DAYS, :to_s, :humanize %>
```

View : display

```
<%= activity.day.humanize %>
```

Keep it simple and you will extend it later if needed :)