# Rails, converting an integer to array offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

Based on feedback, I am revising this question.  How do i convert an integer array to a set of values displayed on the view page using the Constants (defined in the model).  I can do it on my form page but have not figured it out for the Index.

On an Index Page (if dbase has grades: [0, 1, 2], the page should display as A+, A, B)

something like what is done for days of the week (e.g. http://hightechsorcery.com/2010/02/16/ruby-arrays-and-hashes-and-days-of-the-week/

```
....
<h4 class="h3"><%= @gradestemp %>
```

**CONTROLLER** Labels Controller

```
  def index
    @labels = current_user.labels
    grad = []
    @gradestemp = Contact::GRADES.each_with_index { |x, i| grad << [x, i] }
    render
  end
```

**MODEL**  NB: GRADES is a constant - I am trying to also use in Labels
     class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
    NB:  this is in the CONTACT model

```
  GRADES  = [["A+",0 ], ["A",1], ["B", 2], [ "C",3], [ "D",4], [ "-",5]]
```

Am i able to access the Contact GRADES while in the Labels controller?

i have found this SO - which is similar to what i am trying to do: 
[Ruby: How to store and display a day of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590364/ruby-how-to-store-and-display-a-day-of-the-week)

Based suggestion below, this did the trick:

```
<h4 class="h3"><%= print_campaign.grades.compact.map{|idx| Contact::GRADES[idx][0]}.join(' ')  %>
```

Comment: (1) Do you have your controller methods (think CRUD) properly setup? (2) Why is your Label model empty? It should have an association with your contacts. (3) Please narrow your post to **one question**. (4) Edit your post (with the previous details, **not as comments**) and correctly format the code. Paste your code directly in, then click the `{}` button, to format it. I tried editing it for format, but your post was too jumbled with details for me to handle

Comment: hi - thanks for feedback - i updated the question.   Yes, I was thinking my issue was that i was not saving the array properly, but maybe its more of a front end (of how do i take the array (from labels) and render back to display the one Contact::GRADES selected.

Comment: I would suggest that you post any error messages you have. How do you know it is not saving correctly? Does it display right in the database, but not in the view?

Comment: Okay -see above - on the form input, i replaced the Contact::GRADES to be explicit and this now works so  when go via EDIT, it displays the collection I had picked ( A+, A, B).  So why doesn't referencing the Contact::GRADES work on EDIT?

Comment: Have you done the Getting Started section on Rails Guides? I suggest doing that before a more complicated app. Your question is still difficult to understand, as you post a lot of code without much organization. (You have two MODELS sections in the question)

Comment: hey thanks.  yes, the 2 models are relevant -hence why i posted them both. I am trying not to duplicate the code in the second.  Anyway, I think i have figured out by just posting it.    if you want me to delete this completely (as it may be confusing for others), just let me know and I will.  many thanks for questions - it brought some clarity to what i am doing.

Comment: Not very clear, but if you just want to convert array like [1,2,3] why not just do   [1,2,3].map{|idx| grade[idx]}.join(' ')

Comment: @tomsoft  - that did the trick great. many thanks.   <%= print_campaign.grades.compact.map{|idx| PrintCampaign::GRADES[idx][0]}.join(' ')  %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0, 1, 2].map {|g| Contact::GRADES.select.map {|letter, val| val == g; letter}`

Really though `GRADES` seems much better off as a `Hash`:

`GRADES = {
  "A+" => 0,
  "A" => 1,
  ..
}`

Then you lookup would be much simpler

`[0, 1, 2].map {|g| Contact::GRADES.key(g) }`